# Subtracting datetime from a week in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have data likes this:

```
DT         DOW  C    O
3/16/2019   6   B   100
3/17/2019   0   B   218
3/18/2019   1   B   124
3/19/2019   2   B   130
3/20/2019   3   B   137
3/21/2019   4   B   165
3/22/2019   5   B   153
3/23/2019   6   B   197
3/24/2019   0   B   225
3/25/2019   1   B   133
```

Now I want to add a new column `'Growth'` which is defined by orders-orders corresponding to the week 03/16/2019 to 03/22/2019 divided by the orders

For example, for the DT `03/24/2019` the DT corresponding to it is `03/17/2019` since both are mondays. so the answer would be 225-218/225=0.03. Similarly, for `03/25/2019` the date to subtract from is `03/18/2019`.

Note we only subtract from the week `03/16/2019` to `03/22/2019`.

Note that the DT columns have dates till the month of May and growth column will be blank from 03/16/2019 to 03/22/2019. It will start from 03/23/2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all datetimes are consecutive first subtract values create by removed duplicates by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then divide by column `O` for all rows with omit first - so assigned to `df.loc[mask, 'new']`:

```
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])

mask = df.duplicated('DOW')
s = df['DOW'].map(df[~mask].set_index('DOW')['O'])
df.loc[mask, 'new'] = df['O'].sub(s).div(df['O'])

print (df)
          DT  DOW  C    O       new
0 2019-03-16    6  B  100       NaN
1 2019-03-17    0  B  218       NaN
2 2019-03-18    1  B  124       NaN
3 2019-03-19    2  B  130       NaN
4 2019-03-20    3  B  137       NaN
5 2019-03-21    4  B  165       NaN
6 2019-03-22    5  B  153       NaN
7 2019-03-23    6  B  197  0.492386
8 2019-03-24    0  B  225  0.031111
9 2019-03-25    1  B  133  0.067669
```

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - OK, can you add expected output?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - How looks new column from sample data? Because it missing in question....

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - Or you need `df['new'] = df.groupby('DOW')['O'].pct_change()` ?

Comment: for example I tried a date 04/10/2019 the O is 166 and DOW is 3 so the corresponding date in the week 03/16/2019 to 03/22/2019 is  2019-03-20 so the answer should be 166 (from my data) -137 /166 =0.17 but answer your code generated is 0.03

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - ok, so is possible change question data with data from comment? and add expected output for all data?

Comment: Okay ill do that..ill fill a few rows since I have to do it manually

Comment: Is your code subtracting from the week 03/16/2019 to 03/22/2019 for every row corresponding to the DOW?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - no, it shift previous week values and then subtract

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - It seems you need something else :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207515/discussion-between-ubuntu-noob-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
>>> df
DT         DOW  C    O
3/16/2019   6   B   100
3/17/2019   0   B   218
3/18/2019   1   B   124
3/19/2019   2   B   130
3/20/2019   3   B   137
3/21/2019   4   B   165
3/22/2019   5   B   153
3/23/2019   6   B   197
3/24/2019   0   B   225
3/25/2019   1   B   133
>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.DT)
>>> df
                   DT  DOW  C    O
DT                                
2019-03-16  3/16/2019    6  B  100
2019-03-17  3/17/2019    0  B  218
2019-03-18  3/18/2019    1  B  124
2019-03-19  3/19/2019    2  B  130
2019-03-20  3/20/2019    3  B  137
2019-03-21  3/21/2019    4  B  165
2019-03-22  3/22/2019    5  B  153
2019-03-23  3/23/2019    6  B  197
2019-03-24  3/24/2019    0  B  225
2019-03-25  3/25/2019    1  B  133
>>> df['O'].rolling('7d', min_periods = 8, closed='both'
                    ).apply(lambda x:(x[-1] - x[0])/x[-1], 
                                      raw = False)
DT
2019-03-16         NaN
2019-03-17         NaN
2019-03-18         NaN
2019-03-19         NaN
2019-03-20         NaN
2019-03-21         NaN
2019-03-22         NaN
2019-03-23    0.492386
2019-03-24    0.031111
2019-03-25    0.067669
Name: O, dtype: float64
```